# iOS+Linux podcast app that syncs which episodes I have already listened to

Tags: linux, ios, podcast

I am currently using [Poddr](https://sn8z.github.io/Poddr/) on Ubuntu and the inbuilt Podcast Application on my iPhone. I am looking for an application that allows me to sign into an account and have access across both devices to history - currently I have to make them as listened to manually between devices.

I have had a look at a few [articles](https://www.lifehacker.com.au/2018/11/how-to-keep-your-podcasts-synced-between-devices/) and most suggest [Pocket Cast](https://www.pocketcasts.com/plus/) however I am not too keen on a web-application on my PC. I had a look at ShortOrange and [Phenopod](https://phenopod.com/) but it seems that these services have been discontinued.

The application can be paid for (preferred not as subscription) and does not need to be Open Sourced.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst sorely lacking some of the features I am after (Auto-Downloading, Tagging, User Rating etc.) currently I am using Spotify (with the Premium Account, not sure if required) to subscribe to the same Podcasts as used in other services.

This is installed on my iPad, iPhone, Work Laptop and Home PC and seems to (as you’d imagine) keep track of the Podcast I have listened to.